# How to append the PATH while running docker image without passing /bin/bash

Tags: linux, docker, path, environment-variables

I have a docker file:

```
    FROM debian:bullseye as MY-IMAGE
    # #############################
    # DO some customization as per need
    
    CMD ["/bin/bash", "-l"]
```

I am building the image using `docker build .`.

**Case 1:**

When I run docker image without /bin/bash , path does not get appended inside the container

```sh
    $ docker run -it --rm --env PATH="/ADDITIONAL/PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games" MY-IMAGE
        my-image$ ehco ${PATH}
        my-image$ /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

**Case 2:**

If I run docker image with /bin/bash , path get appended to PATH inside the container

```sh
    docker run -it --rm --env PATH="/ADDITIONAL/PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games" MY-IMAGE
        my-image$ ehco ${PATH}
        my-image$ /ADDITIONAL/PATH/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
``

May I please know how can get the path appended without passing `/bin/bash` while running image?
```

Comment: Add `ENV PATH="/ADDITIONAL/PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games" ` to your `Dockerfile` and build it again. Or even run `RUN $PATH=$PATH:/additional/path`

Comment: What's the difference between the two `docker run` commands?  Is there any relevant application source code, or a more complete Dockerfile that does something more than launch an interactive shell?